# Что значит " * text=auto" в .gitattributes?

Tags: git, git-commit

Что значит * ?

Если перед commit-om преобразует все переводы строк в текстовиках в CR

Т.е. CRLF(win)->CR(Linux) LF(MAC)->CR(Linux).

То зачем ещё добавляют *.java text если git и так определяет его как (если я правильно понял)?

К примеру тут Guava (Java): https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/.gitattributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`* text=auto` Говорит git'у автоматически обрабатывать окончания строк (нормализация к LF при `checkin`) для файлов, которые определяются в виде текста, а все файлы, которые распознаны как двоичные, оставлять без изменений.

`*.java text` здесь указываем, что все файлы с расширением `.java` считать текстовыми, это на случай, если не отработало правило `* text=auto`. Соответственно эти файлы тоже должны быть нормализованы (CRLF -> LF). Например, если мы положим бинарь с расширением `.java`, то он будет тоже нормализован.

**UPD** кроме того `.gitattributes`, который коммитится в репозиторий и переписывает локальные `core.autocrlf` настройки, что позволяет обеспечить единообразное поведение для всех пользователей независимо от их настроек git. Преимущество этого заключается в том, что ваша конфигурация окончания строки теперь перемещается вместе с вашим репозиторием, и вам не нужно беспокоиться о том, имеются ли у других, кто вместе с вами работает с данным репозиторием, соответствующие вашим глобальные настройки окончания строк.